# Plotting many 3D functions in one plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I am generating random walks in 3D plot. The numbers of generated random walks is equal to the variable traj. How can I plot them in one plot? I'm looking for something similar to 'hold on' in MatLab.
There is my code:

```
def random_walk_3D(n, traj = 1):

for i in range(traj):

    skoki = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [-1, 0, 0], [0, 0, -1]])
    losy = np.random.randint(6, size = n)

    temp = skoki[losy, :]

    x = np.array([[0, 0, 0]])

    temp1 = np.concatenate((x, temp), axis = 0)

    traj = np.cumsum(temp1, axis = 0)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    ax = plt.gca()

    X, Y, Z = zip(*traj)
    ax.plot(X, Y, Z)
    ax.scatter(X[-1], Y[-1], Z[-1], c='r', marker='o') #the last point
    plt.show()
```

Comment: You create a figure in each loop step. Don't do that and instead call `plt.show` after the complete loop

Comment: So I should use plot.show after the for loop?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Unfortunately it doesn't work. The function creates a plot in every iteration.

Comment: Yes because you call `fig = plt.figure()` in each loop. If you want one single figure, don't create several of them.